# Comment section not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on my first rails application and I am attempting to add a comment section. The comments will fall under each topic. I am seeing comments that are being generated but I am not able to get it configured so that I can input my own comments. I will list below the changes I have made to my code as instructed by my assignment.

Heres a change to my app/models/comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user

  validates :body, length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates :body, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
 end
```

Heres my app/models/user.rb

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

   def admin?
   role == 'admin'
 end

 def moderator?
   role == 'moderator'
end
end
```

I have to also update db/seeds.rb

```
# Create Comments
100.times do
  Comment.create!(
     # user: users.sample,   # we have not yet associated Users with Comments
    post: posts.sample,
    user: users.sample,
    body: Faker::Lorem.paragraph
  )
end
```

Updated my config/routes.rb

```
resources :comments, only: [:create]
```

Updated my app/controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

    def create
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = current_user.comments.new(comment_params)
@comment.post = @post
@new_comment = Comment.new

authorize @comment
    end
end
```

The final adjustments I made was to app/views/comments/_form.html.erb

```
<% if current_user %>
<h4>Add a comment:</h4>
<%= form_for [@post, @post.comments.build], remote: true do |f| %>
<%= f.label :body %>
<%= f.text_field :body %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

I hope that this is sufficient enough for some type of a response as to what I may be missing.  I do not get an error, the box that I am looking for to create a comment just does not appear.  Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

http://oi62.tinypic.com/f35h5y.jpg

edit:

Here is the `app/views/posts/show.html.erb`

```
<h1><%= markdown @post.title %></h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
         <small>
       <%= image_tag(@post.user.avatar.tiny.url) if @post.user.avatar? %>
       submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> ago by
       <%= @post.user.name %>
   </small>
    <p><%= markdown @post.body %></p>
    <p><%= image_tag(@post.image_url) if @post.image? %></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <% if policy(@post).edit? %>
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_topic_post_path(@topic, @post), class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: have you tried removing remote: true ? if you want it remote you also need create.js.erb where you append created comment to your comments div

Comment: You're showing a lot of irrelevant things, and missing some relevant things. Your stated issue is that the form to add a new comment doesn't appear, so the `db/seeds.rb` that you're doing, and the `create` action in your `CommentsController` are both irrelevant. What you haven't shown is your `app/views/posts/show.html.erb` where we would expect to see the rendering of the comment partial, nor the have you shown the relevant parts of the `PostsController` showing `@post` being set correctly.

Comment: This partial is supposed to be rendered from within a view, right? Where is the view code, please?